# Is Idiorm take raw query from database without array of parameter?

Tags: mysql, idiorm

I'm trying to take a query from database to make it run with Idiorm, but I'd noticed that in order to use raw query, I must specify the variable with an array. Can I just take a query from database and assign it to a variable and put it into raw query without specify the existing variables in array?

Answer (score 0):

I am the maintainer of the Idiorm project. If I understand your question properly:

A new method called `raw_execute` has been added to the `develop` branch of Idiorm recently. This should fulfil your requirements I think. See: https://github.com/j4mie/idiorm/issues/93